# Adding COLLATION in postgres

Tags: postgresql, collation, case-insensitive

I am migrating data from SQL Server to Postgres. Since Postgres is case-sensitive, I am trying to add case-insensitive COLLATION but it is failing with the below error -

> ERROR: could not create locale "en-u-ks-primary": No such file or
> directory DETAIL: The operating system could not find any locale data
> for the locale name "en-u-ks-primary". SQL state: 22023

```
CREATE COLLATION main.case_insensitive_collation (LC_COLLATE = 'en-u-ks-primary',
        LC_CTYPE = 'en-u-ks-primary'
        PROVIDER = icu,
        DETERMINISTIC = False
    );
```

Checked the version of postgres -

```
SELECT version();
```

> "PostgreSQL 12.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian
> 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit"

Any idea on how can I fix this or get this working ?

Thanks in advance,

Neha

Comment: Seems to be a Debian problem. [works fine with red hat](https://dbfiddle.uk/1VgO3f3r)

Answer (score 0):

Your collation definition is wrong. It should be something like

```
CREATE COLLATION english_ci (
   PROVIDER = icu,
   LOCALE = 'en-u-ks-level2',
   DETERMINISTIC = FALSE
);
```

[Here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/icu-collations-against-glibc-2-28-data-corruption/) is an article that has some information about that.